# How to remove item from Modal in React

Tags: reactjs

How to remove the displayed content when remove button is clicked inside of Modal.

I am able to remove that object when remove button is clicked from the array but that content still displays on Screen.

I thought removing object from the array will re-initiate the map function which will call again looping and new content will be visible

```
import React from "react";
import { Modal, Button } from "react-bootstrap";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";

let data = [
  {
    Name: "COOL",
    title: "SuperCOOL",
    id: 1
  },
  {
    Name: "DEMON",
    title: "SuperDEMON",
    id: 2
  },
  {
    Name: "SPIDER",
    title: "SuperSPIDER",
    id: 3
  },
  {
    Name: "SUPER",
    title: "SuperSUPER",
    id: 4
  }
];

const RemoveGuy = Name => {
  data = data.filter(person => person.Name !== Name);
  console.log(data);
};

export default function App() {
  const [modalShowing, setModalShowing] = React.useState(false);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Button onClick={() => setModalShowing(true)}>Show</Button>
      <Modal
        show={modalShowing}
        onHide={() => setModalShowing(false)}
        size="lg"
        aria-labelledby="contained-modal-title-vcenter"
        centered
      >
        <Modal.Header closeButton>
          <Modal.Title id="contained-modal-title-vcenter">
            <p>Details</p>
          </Modal.Title>
        </Modal.Header>
        <Modal.Body>
          {data.map(item => {
            return (
              <div>
                <table>
                  <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <td>{item.Name}</td>
                      <td>{item.title}</td>
                      <td>
                        <Button onClick={() => RemoveGuy(item.Name)}>
                          Remove
                        </Button>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
              </div>
            );
          })}
        </Modal.Body>
      </Modal>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use lifecycle hooks to update data so that the UI can re-render with the updated data

Answer (score 0):

Directly mutating your data array will not re-render the component. You need to store that value in a state then update the state on removal

```
import React, {useState} from "react";

export default function App() {

  const [data, setData] = useState([
    {
      Name: "COOL",
      title: "SuperCOOL",
      id: 1
    },
    {
      Name: "DEMON",
      title: "SuperDEMON",
      id: 2
    },
    {
      Name: "SPIDER",
      title: "SuperSPIDER",
      id: 3
    },
    {
      Name: "SUPER",
      title: "SuperSUPER",
      id: 4
    }
  ]);

  const RemoveGuy = Name => {
    setData(data.filter(person => person.Name !== Name));
    console.log(data);
  };
  
  ...
```

I've put these inside of the App function so that hooks can be used. This can be implemented if you have React 16.8.0 or above, otherwise look into using Class based components to use React Lifecycle Methods such as `componentDidUpdate`